# Fallo heroku al intentar realizar un crud en una base mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, heroku

Estoy realizando un api que realiza un crud en una base de datos mongodb.
en entorno local funciona perfectamente, pero ahora que la intento subir a heroku obtengo estos problemas

[image: Heroku logs --tail]

intente usar una uri que sirve perfectamente en web con deploy en heroku y resulta el mismo error

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const app = express();

const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const reportRoutes = require('./routes/reports');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@panic-database-kpamh.mongodb.net/usuarios?retryWrites=true',{
useCreateIndex: true,
useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(db => console.log("db is connect"))
.catch(err=> console.log(err));

//SETTINGS
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);

//middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes 
app.use('/users',userRoutes);
app.use('/reports',reportRoutes);



//START SERVER
app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('Server on port',app.get('port'));
});
```

Gracias... agradezco cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arregle el problema de manera muy rara simplemente cambie el nombre del archivo que levanta mi servidor a index.js y lo agregue al Procfile y ahora sirve todo...No entendi porque paso esto ayer ya lo habia intentado hacer pero bueno ahora sirve que es lo importante